# Problem with flickering data loaded by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

we decided to use live AJAX search on our website and everything works perfectly but flickering data generated by AJAX. When I quickly type a keyword to the search bar, there are multiple versions of results (not all of them are correct) changed/flickered within a second. Also when I retype a keyword, the results are generated again + after like 0.3s they blink/flicker again because a new version of same results is generated. I've read multiple threads on Stackoverflow or other websites but unfortunately I wasn't able to fix this.

Problems:

1. same content is generated multiple times = flickering (would be better to not load it again)
2. success part of AJAX doesn't wait until the correct/final results are loaded = flickering

Can anybody help me please, how to solve this? I'm lost.

AJAX code below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
    beforeSend:function(data){
      jQuery('#datafetch').html('<div style="display: block">Wait a moment..</div></ul>');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
    }
});
```

Example of HTML structure (imported in php as *data*) below:

```
<div id="datafetch" class="boxes">
   <div class="box">
     Post A
   </div>
   <div class="box">
     Post B
   </div>
   <div class="box">
     Post C
   </div>
</div>
```

I used the code from this website (https://code.mukto.info/wordpress-ajax-search-without-plugin/
) + I only modified AJAX a little bit by adding beforeSend event. Then I edited only the final structure of posts generated by AJAX (html structure + php functions). Nothing which would cause flickering imo. Also I debugged my CSS which are okay as well.

Thank you!

Comment: There is probably not enough info here to help - how are you triggering your AJAX?  If it is fired on every keypress you might end up with several AJAX requests running simultaneously, with results coming back asynchronously so each one overwriting the other etc.  Or maybe some CSS issues, depending on how your results list is styled?

Comment: @Don'tPanic hey, thanks for the response! I use this code: https://code.mukto.info/wordpress-ajax-search-without-plugin/
I only edited a few parameters which shouldn't affect it, also CSS don't affect flickering.